# Firestore Connection Issues in Next.js 13 Turbo Pack: Error "Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, turbopack

I have already verified that my internet connection is stable, and I have double-checked my Firebase configuration. I have also made sure that I have installed the correct version of the firebase package and initialized Firebase and Firestore correctly in my project.

In my package.json, I have:

```
"dev": "next dev"
```

There are no Firebase errors. Everything works correctly.

However, when I change the dev script to:

```
"dev": "next dev --turbo"
```

In Turbo Pack mode, I can fetch data from the client side (this has been tested). However, it seems that nothing is fetched on the server side. The function returns an empty array and does not throw an error in the async function. The console displays the following message:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.19.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

Is there anything else I should check or any additional steps I should take to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Good News:
I updated all package of my project, next.js 13.4.
Now, everything seems perfect.**